# Regex to replace specific font-family values

Tags: css, regex, font-family

I want to replace all `font-family` values, there are more than 200 declarations in the code, that's not cool to do one-by-one.

So, I found this [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/UpQQv5/1), it's almost what I needed.
What I need it's just picking the lines that have "Verdana" on the value.

```
(?<=font-family:)(.*)(?=;)
```

```
font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-family: 'lucida grande', helvetica, arial, serif, verdana;
font-family: 'lucida grande', lucida, verdana, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
font-family:Verdana;
font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
font-family: verdana, 'lucida grande', helvetica, arial, serif;

// Should not match
font-family:Helvetica Neue, Helvetica,Arial;
font-family: sans-serif;
/*  font-family: monospace; */
```

Does anyone know how to improve this regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that?

```
(?<=font-family:)([^;]*verdana[^;]*)(?=;)
```

Of course, add flag `i` to match both `verdana|Verdana`.

Answer (score -1):

You have to specify also:

- the string you want to be matched,
- use optional case insensitivity `(?i)`.

`(?<=font-family:)(.*(?i)verdana.*)(?=;)`

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hDSLVH/1)

Comment: I would like to know why the answer is considered wrong.

Comment: Your question is not related to vscode. You should not downvote a question just because it does not fit what you want, but only if it does not answer the question.